# How to sync ForkLift Favourites and settings across computers?

Tags: macos, dropbox

is there any 'easy' way to sync my ForkLift so I don't have to keep updating my three computers every time I add an FTP for example..

I thought about doing a symlink via dropbox but I don't have idea of which folders contain this information.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Luis.

Answer (score 4):

In ForkLift 3 file locations has changed.
Preference stay stored in `/Library/Preferences/com.binarynights.ForkLift2.plist`, while favourites are now stored in `~/Library/Application Support/ForkLift/Favorites/Favorites.json`.
Can be used for restoring backups or with steps described by tech-otaku for sync.

Comment: edit: ForkLift3 has built-in functionality for syncing favourites.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of resurrecting this old thread, I've just had the exact same problem.

According to the developers the next major version will allow syncing of password-protected favorites via Dropbox. As of this writing no release date has been set.

In the meantime you could try this.

ForkLift preferences – including Favorites – are stored in

```
/Users/your-user-name/Library/Preferences/com.binarynights.ForkLift2.plist
```

Move – not copy – this file to your Dropbox. I placed mine in a folder named ForkLift.

Next, you need to create a symlink using the **ln** command in Terminal with the **-s** switch. This is important as simply dragging the file in the Finder to create an alias will not work.

```
ln -s /Users/your-user-name/Dropbox/ForkLift/com.binarynights.ForkLift2.plist /Users/your-user-name/Library/Preferences/com.binarynights.ForkLift2.plist
```

The downside is that passwords are not copied. Also, having ForkLift open at the same time on different machines will likely cause a file conflict with the preference file. But this solution works for me.

Comment: Well, that's a problem from the past now with the new ForkLift version. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the information. One warning: if you use an alias instead of a symlink then ForkLift 3.4.4 will crash at startup.

As others have noted ForkLift 3 has a preference to sync your Favorites using DropBox, but I prefer to make the symlink myself, because it is compatible with any cloud service and allows me to put the folder where I want.